# Can neural networks handle discontinous input?

Tags: input, neural-network, orientation

I am wondering if and how well feed-forward neural networks can handle discontinuous inputs in general.

In a deep reinforcement learning project i want to input an orientation into a neural net. However the orientation angle is defined in the range of [-180°, 180°] with a discontinuity at the boarders. So given enough training samples and time, will the neural network learn that -180° is actually the same as +180° or will it distinguish these values because they lie on the opposite sides of the input space?

Comment: What do you mean that this is discontinous? This function is continous - it has one more property - that f(-180) = f(180). Am I right?

Comment: If i let a robot spin with a constant velocity it real world angle keeps growing continuously: 0° , 180°, 360°, 720° and so on. However, my input jumps periodically at the same time. In that sense i believe i can say its a  discontinuous representation of an actually continuous property.

Comment: But this is discontinuity of the possible stream of arguments - not the values.

Comment: Well, this is what i care about. The input to the neural net.

Comment: Yes, but do you use a recurrent neural network - so the order of the input matters? If not you can easily reshuffle it and it will no affect your model - the same with this property.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem. The value function approximated by your NN will simply map all actions in those states to approximately the same value, since they would be equivalent in terms of exploitation.

So, it doesn't matter if those value are distant from each other; from the agent's point of view, they indistinguishable.

Comment: Agree, ideally my algorithm will "see" that orientations of +180° and -180° will have the same effect. I was just thinking of generalization with regards to the orientation values. Just to make it clear for me, wouldn't it be easier for the NN to learn that values of  0° and 10° have a similar effect than the same for values of 180° and -170°?